# Modifying headers for dll-s

Tags: c++, dll, header

I am trying to find out if it's possible to modify the headers for the precompiled DLLs. The reason why I would like to do it is because I would like to be able to have one version of the DLL library, but in some cases, I would also want to be able to restrict the access to some of the methods in the exposed classes.

My initial idea was to simply remove the declarations of those methods from the header but after I had done it, I started getting some null pointer exceptions.
I was suspecting that it might not work, but what I am trying to establish now is whether this is where the problem is. If it is, can you suggest an alternative solution for what I want to achieve?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one has provided a definite answer to this question, I kept googling and eventually found this thread:
[compiling against a modified header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696776/compiling-against-a-modified-header-file),
which basically describes identical problem. The bottom line is that removing method declarations after compiling the library is a One Definition Rule (ODR) violation and might appear to work, but it is only a coincident. Hope it helps someone else as well.